# make class start on bottom of div problems

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a span start at bottom of the div now I found the answer here.
Not working the way I want it, I don't want them layer each other.

https://jsfiddle.net/j96s0pn6/

```
#wrap {   
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
} 
.msg { 
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
        <div id="theWwrap">
            <div id="wrap">
                <span class="msg"><b>Nickname: </b>Text</span><br>
                <span class="msg"><b>Nickname: </b>Text</span><br>
             </div>
            <form id="theInput">
                <input size="35" id="message">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange your html so `#wrap`, wraps around the form as well. Then give `#theWwrap` a `relative` position, and the second wrap an `absolute` position instead of the individual classes: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j96s0pn6/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="theWwrap">
    <div id="wrap"> <span class="msg"><b>Nickname: </b>Text</span>

        <br> <span class="msg"><b>Nickname: </b>Text</span>

        <br>
        <form id="theInput">
            <input size="35" id="message">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#theWwrap {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#wrap {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Explanation:**

`absolute` takes the position related to its direct - non-`static` parent. Therefore, if two siblings have `absolute` positioning, and the same position (top, left, bottom, right) assigned, they will land in the same area.

**Source:**

[CSS position property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)